Running HttpListener Inside a windows docker container gives "Access denied error"
My HttpListener code is as follows:
HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();                                             httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/");                                                                                                 httpListener.Start();

Application running HttpListener in docker container gives "Access denied error"

The application gives the same error when ran normally but if I run the application as administrator the issue is resolved. If I add the above url to urlacl list than the application run fines with normal user as well. The netsh add url command is
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=someuser

I am using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 as runtime and mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as image.  The image does not support  the netsh http add urlacl command.
How can I bind an wildcard ip to my httplistener and run it as windows container?
